# contains is object has no method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find whether there is some character in my string in JS

Like that :

```
$('.upld_btn').bind("click", function () {

    changeApiFormat($('#embbed').val());

});

if ($('#embbed.contains("?vid=")')) {
....

....
}
```

I've got an error in my google chrome console :

```
Object XXXX has no method 'contains'
```

How come?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `#embbed` is an input value of some kind (because of your call to `.val()` above). So, you would want to pull its value here, as well, and use `indexOf` (`-1` indicates not found):

```
if ($("#embbed").val().indexOf('?vid=') != -1) {
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5qWp/) illustrating proof-of-concept. Enter "Hi", or "aHia", or anything like that (case-sensitive) into the box and click the link, and you will get a success popup. Otherwise you will get a failure popup.

Code used:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clicky").click(function() {
        if ($("#input").val().indexOf('Hi') != -1) {
            alert("Contains 'Hi'!");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        } else {
            alert("No luck!");
        }
        return false;
    ​}​);
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the [**contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector your syntax is not correct, assuming that is what you are trying to achieve:

```
if ($('#embbed:contains("?vid=")').length) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

It's `:contains` instead of `.contains`:

```
$('#embbed:contains("?vid=")')
```